# Best practise to display success in AJAX / HTML

Tags: html, ajax

I hava an Ajax function that GET all users information, and then pass it to the displayUser function.
In the displayUser function, i print it out in table with ID = displayUsers. This is working fine. But i now want to add more html code to this, without having a to dirty code. Does anyone have a good practice for this?

```
   <script>
    $(function () {
       $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          url: '?page=getUserInfo',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) { 

              $.each(data, function(i, item){
                  displayUsers(item);
            });
          }
       });
    });
    </script>

    <script>
       function displayUsers(item) {
           var $displayUsers = $('#displayUsers');
            $displayUsers.append('<tr><th>navn:</th><td>' + item.name + '</td><th>Brukernav:</th><td>' + item.username + '</td></tr>'); 

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "without having to dirty code"?  What exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: well, in this output, I also want to include 3 buttons, and som more information in each row. and there will be a lot of marked out ('HMTL') code. I know there is possible to use template mustache js or something like that. and I have read a little about DOM? but I dont know what will be best practice for this.

Answer (score 1):

I have 2 thoughts. 1 what you are doing good and 2 what I can suggest (also brings in es2015 in discussion).

I see that you are creating an element and then appending it. It is really a good practice and is more performant because leads to less document repaint. You can extend this idea with more things like document.createElement. You can create 3 elements and then append them one by one to parent element. Although you may label it initially with bad looking code, it works great and is a good code.

You can also look into es2015 templates that supports multi line templates. Browsers have good support for it however I'm not sure if you do want to introduce es2015.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into es2015!